# NSXMLParser Error code:5, iphone

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

When i try to parse an xml using nsxmlparser, this error code is showing up, what is this error code pointing to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSXMLParser reference, [Parser Error Constants](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-SW1):

```
NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError = 5
//The document ended unexpectedly.
```

You're likely trying to parse invalid xml document.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It turned out it was the encoding. I used the sign "€", which wasn't properly encoded.