# iphone : error parsing XML: Unable to read response xml (Error code 5 )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

I am using XMLParsing for using my webservice in iphone app.

and i am getting `error parsing XML: Unable to read response xml (Error code 5 )`

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you give part of code ... ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206780/nsxmlparser-error-code5-iphone link if you use NSXMLParser. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError
The document ended unexpectedly.
Available in Mac OS X v10.3 and later.
Declared in NSXMLParser.h.
```

The problem looks like your xml is not well formed. So debug on these lines and you will be able to parse the xml successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the request u r sending. Or look into [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37597-parsing-xml-return-error-code-5-but-url-correct.html

The sixth comment says he has solved the problem.

The following link gives all the error constants

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html